# Access to Blob Storage from PHP Running on Azure Web App

Tags: php, azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to let my PHP wiki which is running on Azure Web App access to my Azure Blob Storage to refer its contents, but it seems to have some problem in referring a blob container.

According to some references, I have installed the composer and microsoft/windowsazure plugin to my app. The location of the vendor folder is D:\site\wwwroot\wiki\bar\vendor.

I also create index2.php (index.php is currently used) with the code below.

```
<?php

ini_set("display_errors", On);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require_once 'vendor\autoload.php';

use WindowsAzure\Common\ServicesBuilder;
use WindowsAzure\Common\ServiceException;

// Create blob REST proxy.
$connectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<account name>;AccountKey=<key>;";
$blobRestProxy = ServicesBuilder::getInstance()->createBlobService($connectionString);


try {
    // List blobs.
    $blob_list = $blobRestProxy->listBlobs("wiki");
    $blobs = $blob_list->getBlobs();

    foreach($blobs as $blob)
    {
        echo $blob->getName().": ".$blob->getUrl()."<br />";
    }
}
catch(ServiceException $e){
    // Handle exception based on error codes and messages.
    // Error codes and messages are here:
    // http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dd179439.aspx
    $code = $e->getCode();
    $error_message = $e->getMessage();
    echo $code.": ".$error_message."<br />";
}
```

However, I got this error when it ran.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'The path of a URI with an authority must start with a slash "/" or be empty' in D:\home\site\wwwroot\wiki\bar\vendor\guzzlehttp\psr7\src\Uri.php:693
Stack trace:
    #0 D:\home\site\wwwroot\wiki\bar\vendor\guzzlehttp\psr7\src\Uri.php(502): GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri->validateState()
    #1 D:\home\site\wwwroot\wiki\bar\vendor\microsoft\azure-storage\src\Common\Internal\ServiceRestProxy.php(124): GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri->withPath('wiki')
    #2 D:\home\site\wwwroot\wiki\bar\vendor\microsoft\azure-storage\src\Blob\BlobRestProxy.php(1181): MicrosoftAzure\Storage\Common\Internal\ServiceRestProxy->send('GET', Array, Array, Array, 'wiki', 200)
    #3 D:\home\site\wwwroot\wiki\bar\index2.php(18): MicrosoftAzure\Storage\Blob\BlobRestProxy->listBlobs('wiki')
    #4 {main} thrown in D:\home\site\wwwroot\wiki\bar\vendor\guzzlehttp\psr7\src\Uri.php on line 693
```

Isn't it possible to access to the storage from this location with this kind of php code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.

As the error messege said, it was necessary to put "/" before "wiki", which was the container name. An instruction on azure.microsoft.com didn't put the sign so that I still can't find the reason why it is the solution though...